# file upload in express js giving problems again

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express, busboy

Though I have read quite a few questions being answered on stackoverflow, I'm still unable to get it to work even after a couple of days of trying. It's my first week with express and node and so I don't know if I'm doing the small things right. I basically want to upload a file and later on save it to the file system, however, I'm unable to proceed with req.files giving me undefined. Please see my code below.

**This is my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var upload = require('./routes/upload.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/upload', upload);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err); 
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
```

**This is my routes/upload.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("");
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send('this is the page you get upon doing file upload');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

**This is my views/homepage.jade**

```
doctype html
html
 head
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
 body
  p select file to upload
  form(action="upload", method="get", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(type="file", name="displayImage")
    input(type="submit")
```

At the moment, I'm hearing a lot of terms like multer, connect-busboy, bodyParser being deprecated from express4 etc but with no real idea on how to proceed. Please advise me on how I can proceed and what code should be added.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of modules were removed from [Express in 4.0](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) and are now [separate packages](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) you have to include. The easiest way to get started with it is to use [express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) to generate the scaffolding for you. This will include and require the correct packages for parsing cookies, and the request body. It doesn't include a file parser however. I put together an example using multer and put it on [Github for you to reference](https://github.com/tstrimple/StackOverflowExample).

After you clone it, you can run `npm install`, and then `npm start`.

One other thing you were doing incorrectly that I fixed was using app.get for your upload handler. You can't use GET to upload a file. In my example I changed this to a POST request. Here are the relevant snippets.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var upload = require('./routes/upload');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/upload', upload);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p select file to upload
  form(action='upload', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
    input(type='file', name='displayImage')
    input(type='submit')
```

Comment: thank you so much for the example;I can't tell you how useful it was. I had been trying things like bodyParser etc for couple of days but with no luck. I later went ahead and modified the code to save the file in a different images directory etc. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a middleware module that can parse your uploaded file.

Like such:

- https://github.com/expressjs/multer
- https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy

Then use the middleware in your index.js, like:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))
```

or

```
app.use(busboy());
```

Comment: ,thank you for the direction. I was able to get it working using multer.